# Need to debug segmentation fault (core dumped) in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Below is the function that takes a character array allowing max 10 characters and checks if its lesser than 9999999999.0. I am getting "segmentation fault(core dumped) error during run time. Please someone help me debug this function.

```
bool validate(char* token)
{
    int i=0, count=0;
    char* temp = 0;

    while(token[i] != '\0' && count < 10)
    {
        temp[i] = token[i];

        i++; 
        count++;
    }

    temp[i] = '\0';

    float check = strtof(temp,NULL); 

    if (check > 9999999999.0)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: `char* temp = 0;`, if you want to use temp, you have to allocate memory....

Comment: Why do you have identical counters `i` and `count`? Why not simply `&& i<10` and scrap `count`? Why not use `strncpy()` or `sprintf()`? Why not run `strtof()` directly on `token`, then test the value?

Answer (score 3):

Allocate memory for `temp`. Because it can have at max 10 characters, you need to allocate memory for 11 bytes (one is for the `'\0'` character)

If you're sure that you'll always have at max 10 characters then allocate it statically:

`char temp[11];`

If that's not the case then you might want to allocate the memory dynamically.

```
int noOfCharacters = // value
char* temp = malloc(noOfCharacters + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out what you're actually trying to do here but...

You are overflowing your buffer.  Your assigned `char* temp = 0;` is completely incorrect and probably the cause of the overflow.  Remember that in C, strings are IMMUTABLE.  Instead, try initializing `char temp[50];` where 50 is replaced by whatever number is large enough to hold your entire end result.  IE- make an array of characters large enough to contain whatever it is you're trying to contain.

**warning**:  Remember that in C, every character takes 1 byte of memory and so a very large data set will need to be approached differently.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to here is to pass the size of the token as an argument to the validate function. In that manner, you can allocate memory to your temp pointer at run time

example

```
...
bool validate(char* token, int size)
{
    int i=0, count=0;
    char* temp = 0;

    char* temp = (char*) malloc(size + 1);

    //continue here

...
}
```